# M1: Frequent kernel panics on `BNBTrackpadDevice::setPowerState`

Tags: crash, kernel-panic, magic-trackpad, apple-silicon

My M1 Air experiences frequent (several times a week) kernel panics due to `BNBTrackpadDevice::setPowerState` timing out after around 10 seconds. [Stack trace is here](https://pastebin.com/5mH2v1Jk) (Pastebin link, because SE thinks my post is spam without it).

The trackpad in question is an OG Magic Trackpad. A search around the web doesn't find much information on this panic. Is there any solution other than "stop using that trackpad"? I'd buy the current model if I knew it would fix it, but given they run $150, I'd rather not without knowing first.

I'm running Big Sur 11.2.2.

Comment: same bug here, several time a week. I have an old magic trackpad connected with m1 some time.

Comment: @janicebaratheon I was never able to find a solution other than to stop using my trackpad. I’m curious if Monterey will fix it, but I’m not going to install the beta just to find out.